# Adding autoscaling to AWS DynamoDB via CloudFormation for already existing table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

Our team was quite excited to see autoscaling feature announced for AWS DynamoDB, and when trying it out by adding configuration in web interface we've discovered that's a good match four our applications' needs.

However, attempts to add the same configuration via CF have proved to be a bit more complicated. Following example as provided in this article - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-examples-application-autoscaling - below is the result, which does not work. Stack detail:

`17:02:25 UTC+0300   UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  my-stack    The following resource(s) failed to create: [WriteCapacityScalableTarget].
    17:02:24 UTC+0300   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget     WriteCapacityScalableTarget     table/TableName|dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits|dynamodb already exists
    17:02:18 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget     WriteCapacityScalableTarget

    17:02:15 UTC+0300   CREATE_COMPLETE     AWS::IAM::Role  ScalingRole

    17:01:42 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  ScalingRole     Resource creation Initiated
    17:01:42 UTC+0300   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  ScalingRole

    17:01:37 UTC+0300   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  my-stack    User Initiated`

My CF script is as follows:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyCustomTableName": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "TableName": "TableName",
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "someAttribute1:someAttribute2",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "someAttribute1:someAttribute2",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
          "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
        },
        "StreamSpecification": {
          "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
        }
      }
    },
    "WriteCapacityScalableTarget": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget",
      "Properties": {
        "MaxCapacity": 30,
        "MinCapacity": 1,
        "ResourceId": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "/",
            [
              "table",
              {
                "Ref": "MyCustomTableName"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "RoleARN": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ScalingRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "ScalableDimension": "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits",
        "ServiceNamespace": "dynamodb"
      }
    },
    "ScalingRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "root",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                    "dynamodb:UpdateTable",
                    "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                    "cloudwatch:SetAlarmState",
                    "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "WriteScalingPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "WriteAutoScalingPolicy",
        "PolicyType": "TargetTrackingScaling",
        "ScalingTargetId": {
          "Ref": "WriteCapacityScalableTarget"
        },
        "TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
          "TargetValue": 70.0,
          "ScaleInCooldown": 60,
          "ScaleOutCooldown": 60,
          "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
            "PredefinedMetricType": "DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone can shed some light as to why this is happening, I'd be much obliged :)

Comment: Oddly enough, it seems that there was an issue with just a particular table - and adding or removing autoscaling via console did not help - script still failed with the mentioned error. The only way to resolve this was to update provisioned capacity (not scalable) via CF, and only then add auto-scaling via same CF script.

Answer (score 5):

Going by the error message

`CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget     WriteCapacityScalableTarget     table/TableName|dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits|dynamodb already exists`

You are creating a DynamoDB resource with the name `"TableName": "TableName"`. You cannot have two dynamoDB tables with same name within a region.

Go to the DynamoDB console and check if you have any such table and delete it. Post that the template should work fine.

Option 2: If you want to go ahead with the existing table, then you can remove the AWS::DynamoDB::Table resource from your CF Template.

Comment: Thanks. My impression from the error message was that WriteCapacityUnits for that table were already created - as they already were, well, cause the table already exists. But isn't removing the table resource itself would mean that the table gets deleted? It has data, which I would hate to lose (or migrate, for that matter). So just to be clear, table resource was created a long time ago, and I just want to add autoscaling to it - by introducing WriteCapacityScalableTarget, ScalingRole and WriteScalingPolicy to CF template.

Comment: I have tried to emulate the same.. First created the DynamoDB table with CF Template and followed it up with adding WritingCapacityScalableTarget, ScalingRole and WriteScalingPolicy to the CF template and performed update stack. It went well. So, is it possible that you have tested some stuff via console and forgot to clear it off?

Answer (score 2):

For me this error came while setting up auto-scaling for an already existing dynamo table. Make sure you've removed any manual (via console) auto-scaling that you've set up for that dynamo table. Then re-execute and the stack would reach the `UPDATE_COMPLETE` stage.

Comment: Confirmed. I had created and subsequently deleted a DynamoDB table via the AWS Console.  When attempting to create a table of the same name with auto-scaling rules via CloudFormation, it complained that the Auto-Scaling policies for the table already existed.  I needed to re-create the table via AWS Console, disable scaling for the table, then delete the table. Only after doing that did the CloudFormation succeed.